# How do you get a list of the names of all files in a directory using React?

Tags: reactjs, file, directory

I would like to save the name of all the files that there is a local directory in an array, to be able to show them later in a list using React.

I know that in NodeJs i can use:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var files = fs.readdirSync('./directory/');
```

But it doesn´t work in react.

Answer (score 0):

Node is JavaScript engine running as a program on your computer/server. It doesn't have the `window` object, but it has its own features like the ability of reading and editing files in directories.

React application is working in the browser and it is limited by the browser, you can't read private files from the user computer with JavaScript because it wouldn't be safe.

If you want to read the list of files in a directory on your server you need to implement some kind of backend, for example, you can use the Node process running as an API on the server, but a simple PHP file would work too. That API should return JSON with the list of files in a directory.

It is harder to read a list of files on a user computer, the easiest solution is to inform the user that they need to upload the files with `<input type="file">` and read them then.